# Scaling fixed size page to width of screen?

Tags: css, html, viewport, fluid-layout, firefox-os

On Chrome 40 for Android, scaling a fixed width page to fit the screen's width is simple. One uses the `viewport` meta tag and specifies the content's width and disables user-scaling:

[image: Screenshot showing content scaled to width in Chrome 40 for Android]

In the Firefox OS 2.2 simulator the same code does *not* work:

[image: Screenshot showing content scaled to width in]

*How can I fit fixed width content to screen width in the Firefox OS browser?*

**Code:**

- `index.html`:

  ```
  <!doctype html>

  <title>Viewport test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000,user-scalable=0" />

  Test
  ```
- `index.css`:

  ```
  * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }

  body {
      font-size: 50px;
      width: 990px;
      border: 5px solid lightblue;
  }
  ```

Comment: @adkmatey I see nothing wrong, and the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) says: *"This document was successfully checked as HTML5!"*

Answer (score 0):

I use the following meta tag and it works: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the properly scaled page in Firefox OS?